# auto-refresh a user's OAuth2 tokens for access to the Azure Graph API

Tags: spring-boot, azure, kotlin, oauth-2.0

TL;DR:  I readily admit to not fully understanding OAuth2 flows and don't know how to persist access to a user's email inbox.

To expand the previous sentence, we have a Kotlin Spring Boot application, one function of which is to read and process emails send to `support@ourcompany.com.au`.  Since MS now enforce authentication *via* OAuth2, we have to implement client-side logic for doing so. I've got it doing that, **but** whenever the server is restarted, I have to re-perform a manual authentication flow *via* a browser page.  I understand that with OAuth2 it is necessary to do that once but once only, and thereafter it should be possible to refresh the tokens programmatically without human intervention;  especially in the case that the application is restarted.  Obviously this means that the access and refresh tokens must be persisted (stored in a database table).

To start with, I copied and converted to Kotlin some sample code from MS's documentation:

```
package au.com.ourcompany.email

import com.azure.core.credential.TokenRequestContext
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder
import com.azure.identity.DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder
import com.azure.identity.DeviceCodeInfo
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient
import java.time.Instant
import java.util.function.Consumer

class MSOauth2Graph(clientId: String,
        tenantId: String,
        clientSecret: String,
        graphUserScopes: List<String>,
        challenge: Consumer<DeviceCodeInfo?>)
{
    private val deviceCodeCredential = DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .challengeConsumer(challenge)
            .build()

    private val clientSecretCredential = ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId)
            .tenantId(tenantId)
            .clientSecret(clientSecret)
            .build()

    private val myself = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(TokenCredentialAuthProvider(graphUserScopes, deviceCodeCredential))
            .buildClient()
            .me()

    private val graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(TokenCredentialAuthProvider(authSources, clientSecretCredential))
            .buildClient()

    private val requestContext = TokenRequestContext().apply { addScopes(*graphUserScopes.toTypedArray()) }

    fun getUserToken(): String = deviceCodeCredential.getToken(requestContext).block()!!.token

    @Throws(java.lang.Exception::class)
    fun getAppOnlyToken(): String = clientSecretCredential.getToken(requestContext).block()!!.token

    fun getUser() = myself
            .buildRequest()
            .select("displayName,mail,userPrincipalName")
            .get()

    fun getMailboxes() = myself
            .mailFolders("inbox")
            .childFolders()
            .buildRequest()
            .get()

    // Ensure client isn't null@get:Throws(Exception::class)val inbox:MessageCollectionPage
    fun getInbox(pageSize: Int, pageCount: Int, folderName: String, afterStamp: Instant) = myself
            .mailFolders(folderName)
            .messages()
            .buildRequest()
            .select("from,receivedDateTime,subject,body")
            .filter("receivedDateTime ge $afterStamp")
            .skip(pageSize * pageCount)
            .top(pageSize)
            .orderBy("receivedDateTime DESC")
            .get()
}

private val authSources = listOf("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default")
```

Then use that to obtain credentials for the support user:

```
    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.javaClass)

    private var userCode: String? = null

    private var authenticationURL: String? = null

    /**
     * AcceptChallenge &mdash; called when challenge is accepted
     */
    private inner class AcceptChallenge: Consumer<DeviceCodeInfo?>
    {
        override fun accept(challenge: DeviceCodeInfo?) {
            if (challenge != null) {
                userCode = challenge.userCode
                authenticationURL = challenge.verificationUrl
                 logger.info("CHALLENGE: U=\"${challenge.userCode}\" V=\"${challenge.verificationUrl}\" D=\"${challenge.deviceCode}\" X=\"${challenge.expiresOn}\"")
            } else
                userCode = null
        }
    }

    private val graph = MSOauth2Graph(platformConfiguration.credentials.azureOAuth2AppId,
                platformConfiguration.credentials.azureOAuth2TenantId,
                platformConfiguration.credentials.azureSecretValue,
                platformConfiguration.deployment.azureGraphUserScopes.split(",").dropLastWhile{it.isEmpty()},
                AcceptChallenge())

    @OptIn(DelicateCoroutinesApi::class)
    @ResponseBody @GetMapping("/azlogin")
    private fun loginToAD(): ResponseEntity<String> {
        GlobalScope.launch {
            graph.getUser().let { user ->
                logger.info("logged-in to AD: ${user?.id}")
            }
        }
        // This is crap but using semaphores etc. doesn't work
        while (authenticationURL == null)
            Thread.sleep(1000)
        return ResponseEntity.ok("""
            $standardPagePreamble
            <title>Authenticate support user to Azure AD</title></head>
            <body>
                <form class="onerow" action="/"><input class="onerow" type="submit" value="Home"/></form>
                <br/><br/>
                Click <a href="$authenticationURL" target="_blank">here</a> and enter the code $userCode
            </body></html>
        """.trimIndent())
    }
```

That lot provides a route (`/azlogin`) which a human can 'visit' and get a credential in `userCode`.

It works;  the application can read the emails.  However, as mentioned, it does require that whenever the server be restarted (which happens several times a week as the application is being rapidly enhanced), the manual re-validation process is repeated.  What we would like is that when the server is restarted, it obtains tokens from its database and does not require the human-intervention step.  What is the minimal change necessary to achieve this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Kotlin APIs, but the first thing that comes to my mind is that a token cache needs to be configured on `deviceCodeCredential`. It's probably keeping the cache in memory by default.

Comment: As I said in my question, I don't really understand this stuff and with all respect, I don't understand your comment that _a token cache needs to be configured on `deviceCodeCredential`_.  I hope this indicates my level of understanding and that will help others to pitch their replies at the appropriate level.

Comment: Is this app running on an input-constrained device, i.e., is the device able to display a UI and make API calls, but it's a pain to sign into? The common example is a TV that can display a UI fine, but most people only have a TV remote available to perform the sign-in (and to throw at the wall when they mess up a single char in their 12 char password).

Answer (score 0):

*I got a little antsy waiting on a response to my comment, so I'll just explain it in both cases (input-constrained device and not).*

To answer your specific question in general, there are 2 ways to do extend the time for access. You can extend the lifetime of the access token or you can use refresh tokens. In OAuth 2.0/OIDC, refresh tokens are intended as a way to get a new access token without re-prompting the user to authenticate and provides a little better security (mainly because a super long-lived token is super risky if it's leaked vs. a shorter lifetime for the access token, but a way to get new ones without re-auth).

Here's [MS's doc on using the Refresh Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token):

```
// Line breaks for legibility only

POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=535fb089-9ff3-47b6-9bfb-4f1264799865
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&client_secret=sampleCredentia1s    // NOTE: Only required for web apps. 
This secret needs to be URL-Encoded
```

Which should only require stuff that you can store and not require any user interaction.

---

First, a primer on [OAuth 2.0](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749). There were [4 **original** flows](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3) or grant types. You can ignore 2 of them (*because security*): implicit and resource owner password credentials. That leaves us with Authorization Code and Client Credentials.

- **Client Credentials**

  - A flow in which there is ***no user***.
  - An app or server or even an IOT device is authenticating on behalf of itself. Your question mentions authenticating a user, so I'm assuming this isn't the case here.
- **Authorization Code**

  - A flow in which there is a user.
  - This flow provides a better opportunity for making things secure vs. implicit and resource owner password.

---

So, since your case looks like it requires user authentication (and authorization), then Authorization Code is the flow to use.

If we're sticking with the original 4. Which is part of the reason why OAuth/OIDC are so complicated. Oh ya, OIDC was added for ***authentication*** and is **a layer that sits on top of OAuth 2.0**. Which also had stuff added later to the original spec.

Now, usually, there isn't a reason to move to any of the newer stuff that got added after the original spec *unless* the original flow isn't adequate for your use case. Or, you can take a look at the [best current practices RFC](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-security-topics), but it does go into a fair bit of detail.

*Some* examples - if your case best fits with what the implicit flow, should no longer be used, describes it is for, then you'd take a look at combining [Authz Code with PKCE](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-oauth-browser-based-apps). Another example, some vulnerabilities were discovered with native/mobile apps which can also be mitigated with Authz Code with PKCE. And, one more example since it's relevant to some stuff in your question, if you were building an app for an input-constrained device, (e.g., have you felt the pain of typing in your email and password on a TV remote to a video game controller?), then the [Device Authorization Code flow](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8628) was created just for you.

---

Back to your specific question but also not an answer to your *specific* question (but, the reason for the lengthy OAuth 2.0 primer).

In your first code block, you used `DeviceCodeCredentialBuilder` and `ClientSecretCredentialBuilder`. Those are for the Device Code Authorization flow (a.k.a. for input-constrained devices) and Client Credentials (a.k.a. the app requesting access is the "*user*" authenticating and authorizing access), respectively.

What you probably want to use, if you're building a typical web app, is the [`AuthorizationCodeCredentialBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.identity.authorizationcodecredentialbuilder?view=azure-java-stable) [for authenticating a user using the Authorization Code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/overview/azure/identity-readme?view=azure-java-stable#credential-classes). Although, it looks like you're using the Client Credentials flow to get a token for your server [to access the MS Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)?

---

Comment: I most likely do want an authorisation code flow.  So the first step would be to substitute that flow for the client credentials flow.  I can't see how to do that, and couldn't get ChapGPT to show me.  Your final sentence is correct;  the objective is to access the MS Graph API, in order to read emails from an inbox.

Comment: I'm wondering if this OAuth2 authorisation code flow is one of those things about which everyone is talking, but no one is actually doing.